# firebug debugging not working in VS2010

Tags: firefox, visual-studio-2010, firebug

i have vs 2010 and debug with Firefox 2.6.3 ..

firebug seems to be working OK except it does not seem to break on js errors..

anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

turn it on.

that helps a lot.